# No se ve bien mi gráfica en plotly

Tags: python, jupyter, plotly

Tengo un problema con una gráfica en plotly. Desconozco por qué se ve de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y al hacer zoom se ve así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
fig = px.line(df,x='Date',y='Word_count', color='User')
fig.update_layout(title='Cantidad de mensajes por mes',
              xaxis_title='Mes',
              yaxis_title='No. de mensajes')
fig.show()
```

Comment: Podría ser que tengas datos continuos y por eso une las barras verticales con líneas oblicuas para representar la función continua "cantidad de mensajes". Para solucionarlo, tendrías que almacenar solo la fecha de los mensajes, sin incluir la hora. Así sería un dato discreto, que solo puede tomar ciertos valores (los días), y se representaría con barras verticales únicamente. Estaría bien que incluyas cuáles son los datos que has utilizado para la representación, para así poder saber si es eso y cómo solucionarlo.

Comment: Lo solucione quitandole el formato datetime a la columna y haciendola como string, creo que plotly no funciona bien con el datetime